# counsel-org-goto to default to current heading

Tags: ivy, counsel

I often use `counsel-org-goto` to move around org documents, and also within other functions I write to perform an operation within a heading. It would be great if there was a way to default the value to the current heading or quickly fill this value in somehow. I cannot see a way to provide this default or make `counsel-org-goto` behave in this way. Is there another function which may provide this functionality or another way to achieve this?